# How can I run Arm MAP without GUI?

Tags: allinea-map

I am using Arm MAP, part of Arm Forge. Whenever I use the "map" command to call the Arm MAP tool, then it shows the MAP GUI. Is it possible to call the MAP without GUI? I want to use it on the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map --profile` to generate the .map file without using a GUI. `map --help` shows more options.

To explore the data in a .map file the GUI is recommended but this can be run on any machine. If you aim to integrate it with other tools (regression testing, continuous integration, comparing multiple runs) then the export options to CSV or JSON will help you.